# Reference a specific field in the details section to make field on the report footer - Crystal reports

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5, crystal-reports-server

My data/table that appears in the details section is pulled from SQL.

It essentially is a basic table with Row Names in column 1 and dates going across row 1 with the final column being a summation of the data.

The data is 4 rows long and what I am looking to do is create a field that I can put in the report footer that will display the same information as any one of the individual fields that is displayed in the totaled column (last column) of the table / details section.

For example if the 3rd row totaled 12 (in the details section of the report), I would like to create a standalone field that will display the 12 in the report footer.

The details section looks like a table: the report footer breaks out certain things from the details section. I need something that will allow me to reference the individual numbers in the details for example: only pull in the 18 or only pull in the 11 into its own little field on the report footer. Thanks.

```
Months    1     2     3     4     total
Jack      3     3     4     5      15
Will      4     7     5     2      18
Mike      1     3     3     5      12
Don       3     5     2     1      11
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your requirement? can you explain more? if possible with a picture

Comment: Hey Siva, I updated my issue above, thanks for any input in advance

Comment: what is your formula for calculating total?

Comment: that is all done in SQL and just comes through as another column. each field in the column is highlighted no matter which individual field in the column you select so all four numbers are selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manipulate by storing in the array and retriving one by  one.

To store in array:

Create a formula `@Total`

```
Shared Numbervar array x;

x:=x+(total);
total
```

In report footer write one more formula `@display`

```
Shared Numbervar array x;
x[1] // first element in the same way 2,3,4 will give you all elements
```

Let me know in case any issue.

Comment: I'm getting an error: subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array

Comment: Ok I dropped the first part of what you wrote in the details and everything is working accordingly now. Thank you very very much.